# Spring Security and Azure AD PreAuthorize hasRole is not working

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot

I'm going through a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory#configure-and-compile-your-spring-boot-application) on Microsoft Docs on how to secure my Spring MVC application using Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory. I'm trying to secure the admin area of my site. I have a @PreAuthorize annotation on a controller method that I only want users in the admin group to have access to. I am able to get a login prompt, but after succesfully logging in I get a 403 for that controller method. When I remove the @PreAuthorize annotation, I can log in and access the method just fine.

Here is the controller method:

```
@Controller
public class PostController {

    ...

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
    @RequestMapping(path = "/admin/post", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPost(@ModelAttribute("post") Post post, Model model) {
        List<Tag> tags = tagService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("tags", tags);
        return "post";
    }

    ...
```

Here is the WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
    }
}
```

Here is the application.properties:

```
# Azure AD
# Specifies your Active Directory ID:
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=<my-ad-tenant-id>

# Specifies your App Registration's Application ID:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=<my-app-registration-app-id>

# Specifies your App Registration's secret key:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=<my-client-secret>

# Specifies the list of Active Directory groups to use for authorization:
azure.activedirectory.activeDirectoryGroups=admin
```

Here is the app registration manifest:

```
{
    "id": "<id>",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "<app-id>",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-04-10T23:37:26Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "test",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2299-12-31T05:00:00Z",
            "keyId": "<key-id>",
            "startDate": "2020-04-10T23:39:47.917Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2020-04-10T23:39:48.4572747Z",
            "hint": "SVb",
            "displayName": "test key"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "test.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "<resource-app-id>",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "<resource-access-id>",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Here's the group in Azure:

[image]

The user I'm signing in with is a member of this group. According to the documentation, only users that are not authorized should receive a 403. I've tried changing the hasRole() parameter to 'ROLE_admin' but that does not work. I've also tried to configure the hasRole("admin") in the WebSecurityConfig.java like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("admin")
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
}
```

But that does not work either. I've been at this for a couple of days but I cannot figure out why I'm getting a 403 when the user I'm signing in with is in the admin group.

EDIT

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>me.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-me</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>test.me</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.2.0</azure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You can view the [Microsoft Spring Boot / Azure AD sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample) in GitHub.

Comment: Have you tried to configure group claim(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-groups-optional-claims)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research, if we want to retrieves user's group membership using graph API which requires the registered app to have `Direcory.AccessAsUser.All` permissions. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter#register-the-application-in-azure-ad) and the [document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-sample#how-to-run-this-sample).

For example

1. Update permissions
   [image]
2. application.properties

```
# Azure AD
# Specifies your Active Directory ID:
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=<my-ad-tenant-id>

# Specifies your App Registration's Application ID:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=<my-app-registration-app-id>

# Specifies your App Registration's secret key:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=<my-client-secret>

# Specifies the list of Active Directory groups to use for authorization:
azure.activedirectory.activeDirectoryGroups=SQLAdmin

# Configure log level
logging.level.root=Debug
```

3. WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
    }
}
```

4. Controller

```
 @Autowired
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SQLAdmin')")
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @ResponseBody
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! One question. I see that you have the Autowired annotation on the public String helloWorld() method. When I put the Autowired annotation on my controller method, I get the following error: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'me.model.Post' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute(name="", value="post", binding=true)}.

Comment: @slugophl Regarding the issue, please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception